# Sketch a single graph of a function f(x) that satisfies all the following properties

Tags: calculus

Sketch a single graph of a function f(x) that satisfies all the following properties:

• $lim_{x\rightarrow 1} f(x) = 3$ but $f(1) = −4$

• limx→2−f(x) = 5, limx→2+f(x) = −1 but f(2) is neither value

• $lim_{x\rightarrow 4} f(x) = +\infty$

• limx→−1−f(x) = +∞ and limx→−1+f(x) = −∞

• lim x→−∞f(x) = −2 and lim x→+∞f(x) = −∞

Comment: Welcome to SE.  Take a look around and you'll notice that questions are better received (and answered) when the poster explains the context a bit more and also shows what they tried and where they got stuck, rather than "here is a question how do you do it".  Additionally please try the inline version of TeX to better express the math symbols. I made a few small edits above to illustrate this.

Answer (score 1):

For graphing this kind of problem, you need to understand the general behavior of a graph in the limit points.

be aware that the notation with a minus after a number indicates the limit coming from the left while the plus sign indicates the limit coming from the right.

With that in mind, we can see that:

- We have a jump @ $x = 1$
- $\lim_{x \to 1} f(x)=3 \text{ but } f(1)=4$
- We have a discontinuity @ $x = 2$
- $\lim_{x \to 2-}f(x)=5, \lim_{x \to 2+}f(x)=-1$
- @ x = 4 your function goes to $+\infty$
- Again, your function is discontinuous on $x=-1$
- $\lim_{x \to 1-}f(x)=+\infty, \lim_{x \to 1+}f(x)=-\infty$
- Lastly, this is how your graph behaves in both positive and negative ends: $\lim_{x \to −\infty}f(x) = −2, \lim_{x \to +\infty}f(x) = −∞$

With this information, you can sketch a graph respecting these rules. The main idea is to create a graph based on the information you have about the limits and connect the dots. I imagine you don't need to add information about specific points.

e.g.
[image: example sketch]

I hope this information is helpful for you.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is your graph accurate?

Comment: @yangyaobin are infinitely many possible alternatives of functions that could fulfill your question requirements so asking for an **accurate one** don't have any sense

Comment: @yangyaobin, as mentioned there are a lot of possible combinations given that you did not state anything related to concavity or any information that would limit the response to a single graph.

I hope this was helpful!